# Question about boundary points on sets on complex planes

Tags: complex-analysis

The puncture disk $0<|z| \leq 1$ where $z$ is a complex number is neither open nor closed. Why? An open set is a set that doesn't contain boundary points. In this case, this property doesn't hold because the points $|z|=1$ are included in the set. How come it's not a closed set? The point $(0,0)$ is not included, but it's not a boundary point.

Comment: Nice editing, I always wondered how to ask questions that imply negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin is a boundary point of this set. The punctured disk contains many sequences that converge to $0$, and so $0$ must be in the closure. As it's not in the set, the set is not closed.

The boundary is the closure minus the interior, so the boundary of the punctured disk is the circle and the origin.

Comment: what's the definition of a boundary point?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoundaryPoint.html

Comment: https://sites.oxy.edu/ron/math/312/04/ws/05.pdf. I am following this definition. If that's  true, then (0,0) is not a boundary point because it has neighborhoods that don't contain points out of the set.

Comment: Every neighborhood of 0 contains points in the punctured disk, but also contains 0, which is not in the set

Comment: I can see a very weird logic behind it that I can't really tackle down.

Comment: if a set is open then it doesn't contain any boundary point. If it's not open then it's closed. (0,0) is a boundary point because all of it's neighborhoods contain points that are in the set and 0 which is not set and 0 is not included in the set, so it can't be closed. xd. That took a while. I see that I started to purse math so late XD.

Comment: As this exercise shows, not open doesn't imply closed. As you correctly point out however open sets do not contain their boundary points, and existence of a boundary depends on the overall context of the set. E.g., (0,1) has 0 and 1 as its boundary as an open set in R, but as a stand-alone (non-complete) metric space (0,1) has no boundary